# Use rle to group by runs when using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, run-length-encoding

In R, I want to summarize my data after grouping it based on the runs of a variable `x` (aka each group of the data corresponds to a subset of the data where consecutive `x` values are the same). For instance, consider the following data frame, where I want to compute the average `y` value within each run of `x`:

```
(dat <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), y=1:7))
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 2 1 2
# 3 1 3
# 4 2 4
# 5 2 5
# 6 1 6
# 7 2 7
```

In this example, the `x` variable has runs of length 3, then 2, then 1, and finally 1, taking values 1, 2, 1, and 2 in those four runs. The corresponding means of `y` in those groups are 2, 4.5, 6, and 7.

It is easy to carry out this grouped operation in base R using `tapply`, passing `dat$y` as the data, using `rle` to compute the run number from `dat$x`, and passing the desired summary function:

```
tapply(dat$y, with(rle(dat$x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)), mean)
#   1   2   3   4 
# 2.0 4.5 6.0 7.0
```

I figured I would be able to pretty directly carry over this logic to dplyr, but my attempts so far have all ended in errors:

```
library(dplyr)
# First attempt
dat %>%
  group_by(with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
  summarize(mean(y))
# Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'

# Attempt 2 -- maybe "with" is the problem?
dat %>%
  group_by(rep(seq_along(rle(x)$lengths), rle(x)$lengths)) %>%
  summarize(mean(y))
# Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

For completeness, I could reimplement the `rle` run id myself using `cumsum`, `head`, and `tail` to get around this, but it makes the grouping code tougher to read and involves a bit of reinventing the wheel:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(run=cumsum(c(1, head(x, -1) != tail(x, -1)))) %>%
  summarize(mean(y))
#     run mean(y)
#   (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1     1     2.0
# 2     2     4.5
# 3     3     6.0
# 4     4     7.0
```

What is causing my `rle`-based grouping code to fail in `dplyr`, and is there any solution that enables me to keep using `rle` when grouping by run id?

**Update**: As of 2023, this appears to have been fixed by the dplyr package, such that my original code works fine, and there's no need for any workarounds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option seems to be the use of `{}` as in:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(yy = {yy = rle(x); rep(seq_along(yy$lengths), yy$lengths)}) %>%
    summarize(mean(y))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#     yy mean(y)
#  (int)   (dbl)
#1     1     2.0
#2     2     4.5
#3     3     6.0
#4     4     7.0
```

It would be nice if future dplyr versions also had an equivalent of data.table's `rleid` function.

---

I noticed that this problem occurs when using a `data.frame` or `tbl_df` input but not, when using a `tbl_dt` or `data.table` input:

```
dat %>% 
    tbl_df %>% 
    group_by(yy = with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
    summarize(mean(y))
Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'

dat %>% 
    tbl_dt %>% 
    group_by(yy = with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
    summarize(mean(y))
Source: local data table [4 x 2]

     yy mean(y)
  (int)   (dbl)
1     1     2.0
2     2     4.5
3     3     6.0
4     4     7.0
```

I reported this as an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1661) on dplyr's github page.

Comment: Looks like the issue got closed as an example of https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1400, which they appear to be working on.

Comment: This is great. Can you either explain or direct me to documentation on how "{}" works within the group_by call here? Googling "dplyr {}" is not particularly effective but perhaps there is a fancy name for this type of call here? Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan, that's not a dplyr specific function. It's from base R and you can check out `help("{")`

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly create a grouping variable `g` it more or less works:

```
> dat %>% transform(g=with(rle(dat$x),{ rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)}))%>%                                   
 group_by(g) %>% summarize(mean(y))
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

      g mean(y)
  (int)   (dbl)
1     1     2.0
2     2     4.5
3     3     6.0
4     4     7.0
```

I used `transform` here because `mutate` throws an error.