# Calculate time elapsed within runs of a variable

Tags: r

I have an data file with a time and output column.
The output column consists of values 1 and 2.
For each run of the output column where it takes the value 2, I want to compute the total time elapsed during the run, namely the end time minus the start time. For example:

```
    time          output       total
      2                2           4-2=2
      4                2
      6                1
      8                2           10-8=2
      10               2
      12               1
      14               1
      16               1
      18               2           22-18=4
      20               2
      22               2
```

Is there some easy way to so this for large data frames?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you need `lag` or `diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the time elapsed in each run of output variable where that variable is equal to 2.

One approach would be to [use dplyr to group by runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246453/use-rle-to-group-by-runs-when-using-dplyr), filter to runs of output type 2, and then compute the elapsed time:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(run={x = rle(output) ; rep(seq_along(x$lengths), x$lengths)}) %>%
  filter(output == 2) %>%
  summarize(total=max(time)-min(time))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#     run total
#   (int) (dbl)
# 1     1     2
# 2     3     2
# 3     5     4
```

This could also be done in base R using the `rle` function:

```
x <- rle(dat$output)
unname(tapply(dat$time, rep(seq_along(x$lengths), x$lengths), function(x) max(x)-min(x))[x$values == 2])
# [1] 2 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. I created a group variable called `foo` with `rleid()`. For each group, I subtracted the first `output` value from the last `output` value, which is `total`. Then, I replaced all values in `total` with NA where `output` is not 2. Then, for each group, I assigned the a vector including the first value of `total` and NAs. Finally, I dropped the group variable.

```
library(data.table)

mydf <- data.frame(time = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22),
                   output = c(2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2))

setDT(mydf)[, foo := rleid(output)][,
    total := last(time) - first(time), by = "foo"][,
    total := replace(total, which(output !=2), NA)][,
    total := c(total[1L], rep(NA, .N - 1)), by = "foo"][, -3, with = FALSE][]

#    time output total
# 1:    2      2     2
# 2:    4      2    NA
# 3:    6      1    NA
# 4:    8      2     2
# 5:   10      2    NA
# 6:   12      1    NA
# 7:   14      1    NA
# 8:   16      1    NA
# 9:   18      2     4
#10:   20      2    NA
#11:   22      2    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you wanted to group by 'runs' of outlook ?

First we need to index the 'runs'. I created a function based on rle (I couldn't find anything to do this but it probably already exists).

```
indexer <-function(x){
  run <- rle(x)$length
  size <- length(run)
  value <- c()
  for(i in 1:size){
    value = c(value, rep(i,run[i]))
    }
  value
  }

df$index <- indexer(df$output)

df %>% group_by(index) %>% mutate(total = max(time) - min(time))

    time output index total
1      2      2     1     2
2      4      2     1     2
3      6      1     2     0
4      8      2     3     2
5     10      2     3     2
6     12      1     4     4
7     14      1     4     4
8     16      1     4     4
9     18      2     5     4
10    20      2     5     4
11    22      2     5     4
```